# Mean, Standard Deviation

Tags: mean

Babies were weighed just after being born and here are the results:

Mean weight: 5.33 lbs,
Standard Deviation: 0.65, 
A baby severely underweight classified by the hospital is 4.85 lbs

The hospital wants to take a picture of the 10% heaviest babies born in that hospital. What would be the lightest weight to qualify for a photo?

Using the normalcdf function, I believe the number of underweight babies is 0.23. Not even sure if that's correct.

Comment: Please consider adding the tag [tag:self-study] and follow the guidelines after reading its wiki.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Do you want to post your code or explain what your steps are?

Comment: You are assuming a normal distribution as a given. That has to be stated explicitly or the question has no answer.

Comment: @Kimberly It's stats.stackexchange.com policy to ask posters to add the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag to questions which are related to textbook exercises, homework etc... `self-study` tag signals that answers & comments should improve understanding, point you in the right direction, help you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you Matthew for answering my question. I'll look on how to do that. It was from my test today and I remembered that question specifically since I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Kimberly Assuming the distribution of babies weight is normally distributed, you are correct that $\approx 23\%$ of babies would be less than 4.85 pounds.

Comment: Thank you again Matthew! Would I use .23 to find the answer to what would the lightest weight be to be qualified for a photo of the 10% of the heaviest babies?

Comment: What's the basis on which to assume normality?

Comment: Normally distributed random variable: Mean: 0 and Standard Deviation: 1

Comment: Why are you interested in the *lightest* babies when the hospital wants to photograph the *heaviest*?

Comment: Whuber- Matthew explained it below, it was apart of how to get the answer for the 10% of the heaviest babies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable denoting a baby's weight and let $F$ be the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) for $X$. Recall that the CDF gives:

$$ F(x) = P(X \leq x) $$

You want to find a weight $x$ such that $90\%$ of babies weigh that amount or less and $10\%$ of babies weigh more. That is, you want to find an $x$ such that:

$$ .9 = F(x) $$

To proceed you would need to know the distribution of $X$ (i.e. you would need to know what the CDF $F$ is). **Not everything automatically follows the normal distribution!**

---

A useful fact for the normal distribution is that the CDF for a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ can be written as:

$$F(x\, ; \mu, \sigma) = \Phi\left( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \right)$$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF for a standard, normally distributed random variable (i.e. with mean 0 and standard deviation 1).

Comment: Thank you, I was confused what normal distributed random variable was. It was not stated in my question but I'm assuming according to the previous homework it was that the mean is 0 and standard deviation is 1.

Comment: @Kimberly A [normally distributed random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) has a distribution that looks like a bell curve. The normal distribution has two parameters: the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$. The special case where $\mu=0$ and $\sigma =1$ is called the *standard normal distribution*.

Comment: Got it thank you! That's a lot more helpful than my professor. So knowing this I'm assuming I will be using the invnorm function?

Comment: @Kimberly Yes. invnorm is probably $\Phi^{-1}$ (I don't know your system). So $x = \Phi^{-1}(.9) \sigma + \mu $ (of course assuming $X$ is normally distributed.)

Comment: @Kimberly the invnorm command may even allow you to pass in $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (i.e. give you the inverse CDF for a normally distributed random variable with a specific $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: I plugged in: area: .9, mean: 0, standard deviation: 1. This gave me an answer of 1.28.

Comment: so $1.28 = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$ Then solve for $x$. The answer you get will be equivalent to if you plugged in .9, mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Comment: Would x be .10 because I'm looking for the top 10% of the heaviest babies.

Comment: Using the formula I got the answer of 6.81

Comment: I get $.65 \cdot 1.28 + 5.33 = 6.16$. If $X$ follows normal distribution with mean 5.33 and standard deviation .65, then 90% of babies would weigh less than 6.16 and 10% of babies would weigh more. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appericate it!